# Mixing PHP Echo and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, string, echo, quotes

Strange question i have

```
echo "<tr><td onmouseover="xmlhttpPost('obrada.php', 'prva', 'osx-modal-data'); return false;">
<a href='#' class='osx'>".$row->COUNTRY."</a></td>";
```

The problem is in ' in function Javascript i have to have ' and " when i write this kind of exit that is just in normal HTML all is doing nice, but when i use this on exit in PHP i got error?? The problem is when i change

`"xmlhttpPost('obrada.php', 'prva', 'osx-modal-data'); return false;"`

to

`'xmlhttpPost('obrada.php', 'prva', 'osx-modal-data'); return false;'`

the function is not working?? I dont know why?

Txanks in advance on answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "<tr><td onmouseover=\"xmlhttpPost('obrada.php', 'prva', 'osx-modal-data'); return false;\"><a href='#' class='osx'>".$row->COUNTRY."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

add slashes inside your js:
'xmlhttpPost(\'obrada.php\', \'prva\', \'osx-modal-data\'); return false;'

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes. Escaping tells PHP to not consider those quotes as part of the processed code. It still process normally for Javascript though.

```
 echo "<tr><td onmouseover=\"xmlhttpPost('obrada.php', 'prva', 'osx-modal-data'); return false;\"><a href='#' class='osx'>\".$row->COUNTRY.\"</a></td>";
```

Escaping allows you to use whichever quotes you prefer/need.